# 2.77a - Keep foot on the ground with anchor OR do not allow any vertex below certain world Z

Tags: animation, armature, constraints

I am animating a human character. It is bit irritating that I need to go and adjust its feet for every animation I do.

Is there a way, through a constraint, to plant a bone at certain LocRot and not alowed to be moved by the IK? (Actually cannot work well with IK when I think about it).

Or rather, tell the rig that no vertex can cross 0 of Z. That will do it even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can place a bone(anchor) in the desired location on the floor, then add a copy location and copy rotation constraints to the feet targetint the bone(anchor). then when the influence of the constraints is 1.0 the foot will be stick to the floor(the anchor bone position/rotation). you will have to keyframe the influence value that can be easy adding a driver for it.

Comment: My feet are not part of IK, it a seperate bone that is connected to the shin bone which is the one with IK constraint. Because of this the feet dangle when changing poses of the character and have to manually adjust them to sit flat on the floor.

Comment: well, you can place a bone(anchor) in the desired location on the floor, then add a copy location and copy rotation constraints to the feet targetint the bone(anchor). then when the influence of the constraints is 1.0 the foot will be stick to the floor(the anchor bone position/rotation). you will have to keyframe the influence value that can be easy adding a driver for it.

Comment: Would you edit your answer with this answer so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: @EvgeniPetrov edited the answer with the one in the comment.